# Select Top into Different Variables

Tags: sql-server, select

Probably not possible but I thought I would ask;

I want to get the `Top` and save each into a different variable. I know that it would be possible with 3 selects and taking the 1st, 2nd, 3rd from the `Top 3` but I was hoping it might be possible in one statement?

I.E.

```
Declare @Var1 as int,
Declare @Var2 as int,
Declare @Var3 as int
select Top 3 [SAVE 3 RETURNED RECORDS INTO VARIABLES] from Table
```

Comment: `Top` as ordered by what.

Comment: There's a Created On field I'm ordering by.

Comment: add a row_number and use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing for demo purposes you want the `TOP 3 schema_id FROM sys.objects ORDER BY object_id`.

```
Declare @Var1 as int;
Declare @Var2 as int;
Declare @Var3 as int;


WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) RN
FROM sys.objects
)
SELECT @Var1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN schema_id END),
       @Var2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN schema_id END),
       @Var3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN schema_id END)
FROM T 
WHERE RN <= 3;

SELECT @Var1, @Var2, @Var3
```

It uses `ROW_NUMBER` to number the rows then pivots them into a single row result that is used in assigning to the variables.

Comment: "Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator." My schema_id in this context is a uniqueid.

Comment: @windowskm - `@Var1 = CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN CAST(schema_id AS BINARY(16)) END) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` will do the job then.

Comment: "Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

Comment: @windowskm - Declare the variables as `uniqueidentifier` not `char`. Or at least make it `char(36)` if they must be strings. And you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Thanks that actually got Kaf's version working for me too but I'm gonna give it to you cause you got me there. Up votes all round though. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

This is **[another way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2431/6)**:

```
Declare @Var1 as int, @Var2 as int, @Var3 as int
Declare @rn int = 1

select top(3) @Var1 = case when @rn = 1 then val else @var1 end,
              @Var2 = case when @rn = 2 then val else @var2 end,
              @Var3 = case when @rn = 3 then val else @var3 end,
              @rn += 1 
from t
order by val

select @var1, @var2, @var3
```

Comment: Can you find any documentation that guarantees the `@rn += 1` will be executed *after* the other three items in the `SELECT`?

Comment: @MartinSmith, `@rn +=1` is always the one next to current one.

Comment: @windowskm, it works on fiddle please check the link. Can't see any syntax errors. Not sure if this a reason for the syntax but what version of sql-server are you running? Example is on 2008.

Comment: @Kaf - "SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions. Note that effects are only visible if there are references among the assignments." [Quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith: I think it is related to a *single row selection*  when `Select @var1 = col1, @var2 = col2 ..` it does not guarantee whether @var1 or @var2 would be assigned first. Statement about more than one rows starting just after that quote. Yes, I can't prove what is happening inside or disagree with you on that but 10/10 times query brings the same results.

Comment: @windowskm - The `+= 1` syntax is 2008+. In 2005 you can use `@rn = @rn + 1`

Comment: @windowskm; may be try `@rn = @rn + 1` instead. Thanks Martin for the confirmation.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks that worked. Unfortunately now getting the same error as yours Martin - "Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char."

Comment: @windowskm: We haven't seen the actual table structure or data types of the column, so you might get type mismatch issues unless cast/convert them correctly. `What is the datatype of the column?`

Comment: Martins last suggestion got yours and his version working for me so I gotta give it to him. Up votes all round though. Thanks guys!

Comment: No problem. I am happy you are sorted at the end. !